# Office 365: Admin Approval Required when Mail.Read scope is requested

Tags: ios, oauth, outlook, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm trying to create an iOS application that allows to read Office 365 user's email. So, I've created a multi-tendant Azure Active Directory Application and during OAuth authentication I request following scope: `offline_access User.Read Mail.Read EWS.AccessAsUser.All`.

Unfortunately when I try to log in as a non-admin Office 365 user, instead of showing permissions review dialog I get "%AppName% needs an administrator approval".
Could you please help me to figure out how could I avoid "Admin Approval Required" dialog?

Logging in via other email clients (I've tested Edison Mail) with the same scope and to the same account shows a grant dialog (no-one in the organisation has previously logged in to the app neither admin has previously approved it). If more details are needed I'll be happy to provide them!

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Leaving just `offline_access User.Read` in the scope actually shows grant dialog, but popular applications somehow can get all the required permissions at once...

Comment: Are exchange web services enabled for the tenant you are trying to access?  Can you use only graph api access?  It seems likely that the ews scope is your problem since mail.read does not need admin approval.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your comment! I believe exchange web services are enabled..
And it seems that EWS scope is not the only problem - if I leave just Mail.Read admin approval is also required :(
Actually, I've used the same scopes as Edison Mail does.. I guess it's something inside Azure app's Settings?

Comment: Strange. The documentation for Mail.Read says that admin approval isn't required.

Comment: Yep, I'm surprised too... But in fact it's needed for my app :/

Answer (score 3):

Although the `Mail.Read` and `EWS.AccessAsUser.All` scopes do not require admin approval at the Graph API level, organisations can turn off the Office 365 [user consent setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/integrated-apps?view=o365-worldwide) *Let people in your organisation decide whether third-party apps can access their Office 365 information*.

Security best practice recommends that this setting is turned off.  If it is turned off one of two things will happen.

- If [admin consent workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow) is enabled, then the user will get a form where they can submit a request for the app to be approved.
- If admin consent workflow is not enabled, then they will see the "administrator approval required" message.

More information on user consent is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent)

You will need to provide some guidance for users on getting their organisation to approve your app in the case where the user is unable to provide that consent themselves.

I am not sure why Edison Mail is working, although it is possible that its app registration has been whitelisted by Microsoft; I don't have access to the Office 365 admin portal to confirm.

Comment: I must note that user content settings is turned on in the organisation I've tested... That's what confuses me most